# h264 videos not being played by android

Tags: android, android-studio

We provide facility to upload and stream video lectures to different schools. I recommend H264 video codec to be uploaded. We are facing issue on android where H264 is supported by android 6.0.0 and afterwards. Which video format we should be using to stream videos both on android app and web app.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the h.264 main profile is only supported in Android 6+

However, if you use h.264 baseline profile, you can go back to Android 3.

Source: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats). You can also check out other formats that are supported there.

Comment: which software should I use to convert videos to h.264 baseline? I tried to look up a few but couldn't find any.

Comment: FFMPEG is the way to go: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: Used FFMPEG to convert some videos to main and Android 9 will not play them, so there is something else going on.